# "Processes" or "Threads" strategy to fill independant blocks into global array?

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, numpy

**In python2, I would like to fill a global array by filling with parallel processes (or threads) different sub-arrays (there is a total 16 blocks)**. I must precise that each block doesn't depend of the others, I mean when I perfom the assignement of each cells of the current block.

1) From what I have found, I would have a great benefit from a CPU multi-cores by using different "`processes`" but it seems a little bit complicated to share the global array by all others processes.

2) From another point of view, I can use "`threads`" instead of "`processes`" since the implementation is less hard. I have found out the libray "`ThreadPool`" from "`multiprocessing.dummy`" allows to share this global array by all others concurrent threads.

For example, with python2.7, the following code works :

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

## discretization along x-axis and y-axis for each block
arrayCross_k = np.linspace(kMIN, kMAX, dimPoints)
arrayCross_mu = np.linspace(-1, 1, dimPoints)
# Build all big matrix with N total blocks = dimBlock*dimBlock = 16 here
arrayFullCross = np.zeros((dimBlocks, dimBlocks, arrayCross_k.size, arrayCross_mu.size))
dimBlocks = 4
# Size of dimension along k and mu axis
dimPoints = 100
# dimension along one dimension of global arrayFullCross
dimMatCovCross = dimBlocks*dimPoints

# Build cross-correlation matrix 
def buildCrossMatrix_loop(params_array):
  # rows indices
  xb = params_array[0]
  # columns indices
  yb = params_array[1]
  # Current redshift
  z = zrange[params_array[2]]
  # Loop inside block
  for ub in range(dimPoints):
    for vb in range(dimPoints):
      # Diagonal blocs 
      if (xb == yb):
      # Fill the (xb,yb) su-block of global array by 
        arrayFullCross[xb][xb][ub][vb] = 2*P_obs_cross(arrayCross_k[ub], arrayCross_mu[vb] , z, 10**P_m(np.log10(arrayCross_k[ub])),

        ...
        ...

# End of function buildCrossMatrix_loop

# Main loop
while i < len(zrange):

  def generatorCrossMatrix(index):
    for igen in range(dimBlocks):
      for lgen in range(dimBlocks):
        yield igen, lgen, index

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Use 20 threads
  pool = ThreadPool(20)
  pool.map(buildCrossMatrix_loop, generatorCrossMatrix(i))

  # Increment index "i"
  i = i+1
```

But unfortunately, even by using 20 threads, I realize that the cores of my CPU are not fully running (actually, with 'top' or 'htop' command, I only see a single process at 100%).

3) What is the strategy that I have to chose if I want to full exploit the 16 cores of my CPU (like this is the case with `pool.map(function, generator)) but with also the sharing of global array` ?

4) some people told me to do I/O for each sub-array (basically, write each block in a file and gather all sub-arrays by reading them and get the full array filled). This solution is handy but I would like to avoid I/O (unless there is really not other solutions).

5) I have practised `MPI library` with `C language` and the operation of filling sub-array and finally gather them to build a big array, is not very complicated. However, I wouldn't like to use `MPI` with Python language (I don't know even if it exists).

6) I tried also to use `Process` with target equal to my filling function (`buildCrossMatrix_loop`) like this into `while` Main loop above :

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# Main loop on z range
while i < len(zrange):

  params_p = []
  for ip in range(4):
    for jp in range(4):
      params_p.append(ip)
      params_p.append(jp)
      params_p.append(i)
      p = Process(target=buildCrossMatrix_loop, args=(params_p,))
      params_p = []
      p.start()

  # Finished : wait everybody
  p.join()

  ...
  ...

  i = i+1
  # End of main while loop
```

But the final 2D global array is filled only of zeros. So I must deduce that `Process` function doesn't share the array to fill ?

7) So which strategy I have to look for ? :

**1. The using of "pool processes" and find a way to share the global array knowing all my 16-cores will be running**

**2. The using of "Threads" and share the global array but performances, at first sight, seems to be less good than with "pool processes". Maybe there is a way to increase the power of each "Threads", I mean like with "pool processes" ?**

I tried to follow the different examples on https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html but without success, this is to say, without relevant performances from a speed-up point of view.

I think that in my case, **the major issue is the gathering of all sub-arrays OR the fact that the global array `arrayFullCross` is not shared by other processes or threads.**

If someone had a simple example of the sharing of global variable in a multi-threading context (here an array), this would nice to put it here.

**UPDATE 1:** I made test with the `Threading` (and not `multiprocessing`) but performances remain rather bad. GIL is not apparently unlocked, i.e only one process appears in `htop` command (maybe the version of Threading library is not the right one).

So I am going to try to handle my issue with using the "**return**" method.

Naively, I tried to return the whole array at the end of the function on which I apply the `map` function, like this :

```
# Build cross-correlation matrix 
def buildCrossMatrix_loop(params_array):

  # rows indices
  xb = params_array[0]
  # columns indices
  yb = params_array[1]
  # Current redshift
  z = zrange[params_array[2]]
  # Loop inside block
  for ub in range(dimPoints):
    for vb in range(dimPoints):
      # Diagonal blocs 
      if (xb == yb):         
        arrayFullCross[xb][xb][ub][vb] = 2*P_obs_cross(arrayCross_k[ub], arrayCross_mu[vb])

      ... 
      ... #others assignments on arrayFullCross elements

  # Return global array to main process
  return arrayFullCross
```

Then, I tried to receive this global array from `map` like this :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  pool = Pool(16)
  outputArray = pool.map(buildCrossMatrix_loop, generatorCrossMatrix(i))
  pool.terminate()
  ## Print outputArray
  print 'outputArray = ', outputArray

  ## Reshape 4D outputArray to 2D array
  arrayFullCross2D_swap = np.array(outputArray).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(dimMatCovCross,dimMatCovCross)
```

Unfortunately, when I print the `outputArray`, I get :

```
outputArray =  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

This is not the 4D outputArray expected, just a list of 16 None (I think that number of 16 correspond to the number of processes provided by `generatorCrossMatrix(i)`).

How could I get back the whole 4D array once `map` is launched and when it has finished ?

Comment: Change `multiprocessing.dummy` to `multiprocessing`... the `.dummy` module versions are fake versions that do not provide the actual multithreading/multiprocessing capabilities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I believe `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` is a private API so you should avoid it. Now `multiprocessing.dummy` is a useless module. It does **not** do any multithreading/processing that's why you don't see any benefit. You should use the "plain" `multiprocessing` module.

The second code does not work because it is using multiple *processes*. Processes do not share memory, so the changes you do in a subprocess are not reflected in the other subprocesses or the main process. You either want to:

- Return the value and combine them together in the main process, for example using `multiprocessing.Pool.map`
- Use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing: just replace`import multiprocessing`with`import threading`and`multiprocessing.Process`with`threading.Thread` and the code should work.

Note that the `threading` version will work *only* because `numpy` releases the GIL during computations, otherwise it would be stuck at 1 CPU.

You may want to look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54698275/510937) which [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54698358/510937) a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `Threading`version has performances relatively mean, so I try to find a solution with your second suggestion, i.e with the **return** object from the function called by `map`, could you take  a look please at my **UPDATE 1** above, regards

Comment: @youpilat13 You should really try to most a complete version of your code. Python returns `None` when it ends up finishing a function without encountering an explicit `return` statement. I believe you might have a path in your code that leads to such situation.